# How to add random values in a pandas dataframe with specific set of conditions

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I'm trying to conditionally add random values within the expected range.

data =

```
LOT NO  QTY(Kgs)    % PICK      11C     12C     13C      14C    15C     16C
H19       312        6.22                       
H20       936        18.67                      
H21       989        19.72                      
H22       559        11.15                      
H23       639        12.74                      
H24       736        14.68                      
H25       843        16.81
```

Where 11c to 16C are columns with null values(nans) or zeros.

I want to add or replace with random values(int & float) with a set of conditions

1. The avg sum of the values in column `11C` should be in the range between 9-12.5.
2. The avg sum of the values in column `12C` should be in the range between 43-47.
   3.
   4.
   Other conditions are below

```
11C    |    12C   |     13C  |   14C    |     15C    |   16C
--------------------------------------------------------------
9-12.5 |  45+/-2  |  205-230 |  5.0-6.0 |  <1000     |  <1500
---------------------------------------------------------------
```

My Expected Output:

```
LOT NO    QTY (Kgs)   % PICK    11C     12C     13C  14C    15C 16C
H19       312          6.22     10.50   45.30   247  5.46   53  430
H20       936          18.67    10.38   48.48   265  5.64   67  280
H21       989          19.72    10.62   44.38   264  5.66   73  325
H22       559          11.15    10.97   43.52   226  5.54   62  365
H23       639          12.74    10.89   46.53   205  5.71   84  345
H24       736          14.68    11.09   43.76   165  5.62   93  230
H25       843          16.81    11.01   39.96   137  5.68   95  160
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## UPDATED

Ok let's say `df2` is your initial `DataFrame`.Here is an example using a `dictionary` for conditions:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame()
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]],
      columns=['11C', '12C', '13C', '14C', '15C', '16C'])


def n(_min, _max=None, rows=7, getint=None):
    if getint == 'AVG':
        return [round(x, 2) for x in _min + (_max - _min) * np.random.rand(rows)]
    _min = int(_min / rows)
    return np.random.choice(_min, rows)


conditions = {'11C': n(9, 12.5, getint='AVG'), '12C': n(43, 47, getint='AVG'), '13C': n(205, 230, getint='AVG'),
              '14C': n(5, 6, getint='AVG'), '15C': n(1000, None), '16C': n(1500, None)}
for key, val in conditions.items():
    df[key] = val

print(df)
df2.update(df)
```

`df2.update(df)` will update all the keys of `df` that are in `df2` but be sure that they have the same numbers of rows while `update()` will update the existing number of rows.

### Result

```
     11C    12C     13C   14C  15C  16C
0  11.37  43.43  223.43  5.66  126  181
1  11.67  45.08  217.87  5.80   91   16
2   9.39  43.95  218.13  5.24   69   71
3  12.23  44.74  215.62  5.87   11  129
4  12.42  45.86  209.75  5.05    5  132
5   9.49  45.28  227.34  5.83    2    4
6   9.35  45.08  218.40  5.34  129   48
```

Comment: 1.How to replace the values to the `existing dataframe.`                                    
2. Column  `13C` must be int                                                    
3. Is there anyway to round the decimals to two places within np.random.rand

Comment: @Krishna 2 and 3 are updated above. Now in which dataframe you wan to replace?

Comment: One more clarification: `The avg sum of the values in columns should be in the specified range`. but using the code gives random values in the range. Let's say the number of `rows=7`. The average of each column should be in the limits as mentioned in the question.

Comment: for columns 15C & 16C, the average sum should be less than 1000 and 1500 respectively

Comment: @Krishna I think this would cover you to accept the answer in the end :)

Comment: Please don't mind:    for 11C to 14C, values should be in specified range i.e., between 9-12.5, 43-47 so on respectively. `Average sum= Sum of the observations/ number of observations`.  But the average sum of the columns doesn't satisfy to the required condition

Comment: Didn't understand exactly. Above you're writinh 14C shoulb be between 5.0-6.0 and I see that the sum both of 11C is between (9-12.5) and of 14C between (5-6). You need somethin different than this? I see that 12C shoulb in range 43-47 which actually is

Comment: Condition is not summing. The Average should be with the limits mentioned.

Comment: Oh OK that's only for 11 and 12?

Comment: From 11C to 14C, **values and `Average sum= Sum of the observations/ number of observations`** should be in the range of `9-12.5 |  45+/-2  |  205-230 |  5.0-6.0 ` respectively.

Comment: this was really long process, so +1

Comment: @Krishna you confused me a bit, I hope this is what you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like below using np.random functions

```py
df = pd.DataFrame()
n_rows = 10
df["11C"] = 9+ (12.5-9)*np.random.rand(n_rows)
df["12C"] = 43+ (47-43)*np.random.rand(n_rows)
df["13C"] = 205+ (330-205)*np.random.rand(n_rows)
df["14C"] = 5+ (5-6)*np.random.rand(n_rows)

df["15C"] = np.random.choice(1000, n_rows)
df["15C"] = np.random.choice(1500, n_rows)
df
```